# Erlang - extract tuple from list of tuples

Tags: erlang

Hi first of all I'm a beginner regarding Erlang,
I'm trying to extract a tuple from a list of tuples and assign it to a variable.
Consider this dataset.

```
[{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}]
```

For example, I want to assign `{0,25075,-2}` to something like Var1 and so on.

I've tried the following in the shell for testing;

```
Tuples = [{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}].
{Var1, Var2, Var3} = Tuples.
```

But I get this error;

```
ฐ** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    [{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell, if you have already assigned a value to a variable then you must clear the variable before reusing it. Use the command `f().` to clear all current variables, or `f(Var1).` to just clear `Var1`.

Secondly, your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
1> Tuples = [{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}].
[{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}]
2> [Var1, Var2, Var3] = Tuples.
[{0,25075,-2},{0,0,-2},{0,376100,-4}]
3> Var1.
{0,25075,-2}
4> Var2.
{0,0,-2}
5> Var3.
{0,376100,-4}
6> Var1 = "something else".
** exception error: no match of right hand side value "something else"
7> f(Var1).
ok
8> Var1 = "something else".
"something else"
9> Var1.
"something else"
```

You will not do assignments like this over lists very often, though, typically you will iterate and/or use list operations.

Comment: Thank you so much! Erlang is an odd language and will take me some getting used to!

Comment: @SnellyCat Its actually *way way easier* than you're imagining right now because you have been trained wrong, as a cosmic joke. ;-) In all sincerity, Erlang as a language is one of the smallest, least complex you are likely to encounter. Once *matching*, *recursion* and *list operations* become natural to your mind you will suddenly wonder wtf is going on with all the arcane madness and syntax in other languages (and it will really annoy you when you use other languages after a while...). Have fun learning!